# What's the best way to create a line that starts at a point on another line and extends at a given angle for a given length?

Tags: c#, line

I have a program where I need to recursively generate new lines off of parent lines so that it ends up looking like a tree. The problem I'm having is that I don't know how to make the child line at angle A, where A is between 10 and 80 or 100 and 170 degrees, relative to its parent line.

My current algorithm steps are the following:

1. choose a random length (call it newBranchDist) from the parent's (x1, y1) point that is less than the total parent line's length (using distance formula)
2. Find the new line's x-coordinate using the Math.Cos(A) times newBranchDist
3. Find the new line's y-coordinate using Math.Sin(A) times newBranchDist
4. Now we have the (x1, y1) coordinate for one point of the line.

At this point, I need to calculate (x2, y2) that is at angle A relative to the parent line. Any suggestions?

EDIT: Also, my program will randomly choose which side of the parent line to draw the new line. So, sometimes it will be angle A, other times it will be A + 90.

Comment: I can't see anything about randomizing the angle. Do you need to compute it or is it "any" angle within the given intervals? Also, you might post a **short** sample of the algorithm you have this far. Sometimes, it can help understand the issue. Will the line #2 start at the same point as the original line?

Comment: This seems more like a geometry question than a programming question. It's not entirely clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: @MattBurland - The question does seem to be about the algorithm to figure out child branches and I think the confusion is precisely because the OP is confused about how to generate such an algorithm.  He seems to be thinking procedurally and completely missing how to use OO thinking to solve the problem.  But I think you are right that this has a heavy geometry component.  Probably it is that geometry component that is throwing him off OO and making him think procedure only.

Comment: Hi Reuben, Please be aware, that the professionals giving answers here, are hungry for reputation points. It would be very kind of you to vote helpful answers up and - if an answer helped you to solve your problem - you should mark it as the accepted answer, This will show to others, that this question is solved. Thx!

Comment: @Shnugo Yes, I've been planning on it. I wanted to try to get the algorithm working before I gave feedback, but unfortunately I haven't been able to get it working yet. As it is, I changed what I needed to only recursively generate lines at 90 degree angles so that I wouldn't have to deal with the trigonomentry in my algorithms.

Comment: @Reuben Agreeing with Shnugo here. You might want to accept one of the replies (mine! mine! mine!) or point out in a comment what more needs to be addressed. Sometimes, when I have a problem and ask a question, I accept the indeed correct **with respect to the stated question** if not yet helpful **with respect to the actual problem** reply. Then, I ask a new question that better corresponds to **my** issue. That we, the community benefits of more than one question being answered, you increase your skill on problem recognition and someone (me! me! me!) gets more reputation.   :)

Comment: @KonradViltersten You are **very** hungry for reputation points obviously ;-) I'll make you happy and vote your's up (also pushing my "sportmansship") And Reuben, it is **of course** my answer you should accept :-)

Comment: Haha, so much pressure! @Shnugo I do really like your solution since it is more of an object oriented approach. If I come back to this, I will go. Thank you all for your input.

Comment: @Shnugo Graceful style of you. Reciprocated likewise by me, hehe. As for the quality of our replies I believe yours is closer to a full answer because it's more exhausting to the subject.

Comment: @KonradViltersten, yes the OP seems to be King Salomon. We are quarreling around and the third answer's got the acceptance. That's life :-) Thx for the points... Btw: Im good in coding structure, but not so fit with maths. I think, that you gave the better input in this part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you would need to know the angle of the parent line as well as the angle of the child line.  Your terms are confusing so I am going to use a little different.  And it needs to be noted that the angles of all the branches should be stored as angles relative to horizontal, although you will need to calculate them relative to the parent branch to do your 10-80,100-170 thing.  But the calculation for the angle from horizontal is easy enough and given below:

```
1. figure out origin of the new branch<p>
    a. BreakOffDistance = a random number less than the parent length (random distance from the start of the parent branch)
    b. NewBranchOriginX = ParentBranchOriginX + BreakOffDistance * cos(ParentBranchAngle);
    c. NewBranchOriginY = ParentBranchOriginY + BreakOffDistance * sin(ParentBranchAngle);
2. figure out a random angle to the new, child line;
    a. figure out random angle between 10 and 80 or 100 and 170.
    b. NewBranchAngle = ParentBranchAngle - 90 + RandomAngle.
       (all branch angles relative to horizontal, right?)
3. figure out random length of new branch - less than parent?
4. The previous steps determine the new branch - origin point, angle and length.  But to figure out its endpoint so you can draw it:
    a. NewBranchEndX = NewBranchOriginX + NewBranchLength * cos(NewBranchAngle);
    b. NewBranchEndY = NewBranchOriginY + NewBranchLength * sin(NewBranchAngle);
```

Because screen coordinates are turned upside down, you might need to replace the plus signs in steps 1b, 1c, and 4a, and 4b with minus signs.

Also, if you are trying to simulate a tree, I don't think it is right to choose the angle of a new branch as 10-80 or 100-170.  Branches in a tree prefer to grow out and up, and it is not hard to do that in figuring out the angle for each new branch.  Finally, your tree would be much more realistic if you thought of it in three dimensions.  Have a tree that grows branches towards and away from you as well as to the sides.  That too would be fairly simple, but more than you asked for.

Comment: The gist of it seems right to me. However, it does get more complicated than this. Implementing just this algorithm still wasn't working for me (see above comment) -- I was never able to get a line to have its starting (x,y) coordinate on its parent branch. However, I'm sure this is due more to my incompetence in dealing with trigonomentry junk than to a flaw in this algorithm. Nevertheless, I think it's a bit more complicated than this.

Answer (score 3):

Making some assumption on the result, as I'm not clear exactly what you're aiming for, I'd say that the calculation is as follows.

```
int x2 = x1 + newBranchDist * Math.Cos(a);
int y2 = y1 + newBranchDist * Math.Sin(a);
```

Then, you can verify the length by Pythagorean theorem.

```
double lengthSquared = Math.Pow(x2 - x1, 2) + Math.Pow(y2 - y1, 2);
double lengthRooted = Math.Pow(lengthSquared, 0.5);
```

Answer (score 2):

With a class like this you could do the calculations first and draw the whole thing in a third step.

This code is completely untestet. There will be some errors, but you might get an idea how one could do this...

```
public class MyLine {
    private Random random;
    public MyLine(int Level, PointF Start, PointF End, int Angle) {
        this.random = new Random();
        this.Level = Level;
        this.Start = Start;
        this.End = End;
        this.Angle = Angle;
    }

    public int Level{get;set;}

    public PointF Start { get; set; }
    public PointF End { get; set; }

    public float MyLength {
        get {
            return (float)Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(End.X - Start.X, 2) + Math.Pow(End.Y - Start.Y, 2));
        }
    }
    public int Angle { get; set; }

    public MyLine MySideLine { get; set; }

    public void CalculateSideLine() {
        float middleX = Start.X + (End.X - Start.X) / 2f;

        float k = (End.Y - Start.Y) / (End.X - Start.X);
        float d = (End.X * Start.Y - Start.X * End.Y) / (End.X - Start.X);

        float middleY = k * middleX + d;

        PointF newStart = new PointF(middleX, middleY);
        int angle = random.Next(10, 80);
        if (random.Next(0, 1) == 0)
            angle = angle + 90;

        float LengthPercentage = (float)random.NextDouble();
        if (LengthPercentage < 0.5)
            LengthPercentage = 0.5f;

        float newLength = MyLength * LengthPercentage;

        //Now we know the starting point of the new line, its angle and the length
        //I do not have enough time to write the complete calculation down but it's result would be a new endPoint
        //You think of a circle with its middle on "newStart" and its radius = "newLength".
        //This circle you'll have to intersect with the line through "newStart" with the given angle.
        //There are two results, you have to choose the one in the right direction
        PointF newEnd = new PointF(0, 0); //This you'll have to find yourself...

        this.MySideLine = new MyLine(this.Level++, newStart, newEnd, angle);

        //this will calculate a new nested side line and - kind of recursively - go deeper and deeper.
        //you'll have to find a break condition on a certain level.
        this.MySideLine.CalculateSideLine();

        //Be aware of randomly angle of 90 or 0. you might want to calculate two side lines on each twig (otherwise it will not look like a tree)

    }

    //This will draw the line to a Graphics (e.g. look at Form.CreateGraphics() )
    //it will kind of recursively draw down the full tree.
    public void DrawMeAndMySideLine(Graphics g){
        g.DrawLine(Pens.Black,this.Start,this.End);
        this.MySideLine.DrawMeAndMySideLine(g);
    }
}
```